# vim shortcut to traverse the word from right to left

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

Vim shortcut to traverse the words in forward direction i.e left to right is w / W
What is the shortcut to go in the opposite direction?

Similarly x deletes character on which cursor is there. So continuously pressing it deletes characters from left to right. Is there a shortcut to delete characters from right to left i.e characters before the cursor.

Comment: `$ vimtutor` is the most useful 30 minutes you will ever spend if you plan to use Vim seriously. Both `bB` (the response to your first question) and `d^` (the response to your 2nd question) are covered there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b` goes backwards to the previous `b`eginning of a word.
`X` will delete the character before the cursor
`db` will delete from the cursor position to the previous beginning of a word (excluding the letter at the cursor). e.g. (`[]` is the cursor position)

```
first middle la[s]t " type b
first middle [l]ast " type b again
first [m]iddle last " type db
[m]iddle last
```

Of course `b` is just a movement command, so you can tack it on to any command that takes a movement, e.g. `cb` will `c`ut/`c`hange to the beginning of the word, `vb` will highlight it, etc.